# Max date available in data to title

Tags: tableau-api

I wanna put the latest date available in my data to the title. I created a calculated fild `max(date)`. However, it's stuck in measures and not available in the menu when I choose insert in the Title menu. 
Any other ideas how to handle this? Thanks!

Comment: Drag the calculated field onto the Marks card as a detail item. Then it will be available in the Insert menu in the title box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What actually helped to solve the problem is to use LOD. So my calculated field now looks like: `{FIXED: MAX(date) }`

Answer (score 1):

With this approach I assume that you wanted to add last refreshed datetime to Title. If yes, then you just need to double click on Title and then in Edit Title window click on 'Insert' to select `Data Update Time`. Content of Edit Title box can be like -

```
<Sheet Name> refreshed at <Data Update Time>
```

Now to answer your specific question - I would recommend to create a calculated field `max_date` as `lookup(max([Date]),0)` and drag it to 'Detail' Marks. Right click it and select MDY format. After this you should have `max_date` field in 'Insert' option of Edit Title box. Hope this helps!

*Don't forget to let us know if it solved your problem :)*

Comment: Can you verify how many distinct values are there in `max(date)` calculated field?

Comment: Just one date )

Comment: @hamsy Did it solve the problem? Pls don't forget to mark it as the correct answer if it does as it'll greatly help others in case they face the similar situation. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't help either. It still shows 'All'. I can see the date in tooltip

Comment: Did you follow the steps exactly as mentioned in the 2nd para of my answer? If you would have then I believe there shouldn't be a problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To get the max date from your dataset you'll want to avoid using FIXED, INCLUDE, or EXCLUDE. The curly braces by themselves will get you what you're after.

[image]

Add that calculation to the detail shelf of the marks card so it's available to you in the title.

[image: <example>]

Once selected you'll see the max date of your dataset in the title.

[image]

Remember, it won't be available until you add it to your view.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Make another calculated field to convert your MAX date into a string:
`STR([Calculation1])`

Then you'll be able to add this field to your worksheet title.

Comment: It still stays in measures and doesn't appear in the menu

Comment: It will stay in measures, but should still be available as an option for your title. I have replicated this and it's working for me, what format are your fields in?

Answer (score 0):

In my case this issue came up when working on a dashboard and none of the other answers helped.

Create a new worksheet to use as the title in your dashboard.

In the new worksheet, create a new calculation `Max([Date])` and drag it to the Text mark. Then click the Text mark and then click the ellipses, and insert the `Max([Date])` into your title. Then make sure to hide your worksheet's title by clicking the 'More Options' arrow and clicking 'Title'.

[Here is a tutorial](https://onenumber.biz/blog-1/2018/5/31/how-to-create-a-dynamic-title-for-a-tableau-worksheet) to help illustrate.